# Loop through json array of objects issue

Tags: php, json

Hi I'm trying to loop through a json array of objects but I literally get nothing back, here is my attempt.

```
 $jsonurl = 'http://eol.org/api/search/1.0.json?q='."$searchvar".'&page=1&exact=false&      filter_by_taxon_concept_id=&filter_by_hierarchy_entry_id=&filter_by_string=&cache_ttl=';
 $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
 $json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach ($json_output->dataObjects as $objects){
    print "{$objects->title}\n";
}
```

here is the structure of the actual json array.

```
array

0    object
     id     19076
     title  Vulpes
     link   http://eol.org/19076?action=overview&controller=taxa
     content    Arctic foxes; kit foxes; red foxes; red fox
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach ($json_output->results as $object){
    print "{$object->title}\n";
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. The problem was in your array name, which in JSON was defined as "results" not "dataObjects"

Answer (score 1):

one more approach that you can try is to decode the json in to array instead of objects.

```
$json_output = json_decode($json,true);
```

By passing a **varaible as true in the json_decode()** function you will get the json_output as an array which can be easily traversed.

Else

you can loop through

```
foreach ($json_output->results as $object){
    echo "{$object->title}\n";
}
```

Please refer to the json_decode() function php manual guide at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

i hope this could be helpful to you

try to type cast with `object`

```
foreach ($json_output->dataObjects as $objects){
```

let me know if i can help you more